# Which limits does group cohomology commute with?

Tags: gr.group-theory, group-cohomology, limits-and-colimits

For a discrete group G, if $M$ is a direct/inverse limit of $M_i$, is $H^i(G, M)$ the direct/inverse limit of the $H^i(G, M_i)$? Of course, cohomology commutes with finite direct sums, but how about general limits/colimits over finite categories? Thank you!

Comment: Related: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/120808

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ken Brown shows in

- *Homological criteria for finiteness*, Comment. Math. Helv. 50 (1975), 129–135, doi:[10.1007/BF02565740](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02565740), ([free author version](https://pi.math.cornell.edu/%7Ekbrown/scan/1975.0050.pdf))

that group cohomology for a group G commutes with direct limits iff G is of type $FP_\infty$. That is the trivial module $\mathbb Z$ has a projective $\mathbb ZG$ resolution which is finitely generated in each degree.

Comment: I believe all limits are preserved because Hom preserved the and group cohomology is a derived functor of Hom. 

Comment: Don't you have problems since inverse limits are not exact?

Comment: By "all limits" in the comment you mean "all inverse limits" ? 

Comment: By limit I mean in the category sense as opposed to colimits like the misnamed direct limit. 

Comment: My first comment about inverse limits is probably wrong because inverse limits are not exact 

Comment: The answer above though is ok for direct limits. 